# Find K arrays that sum up to a given array with a certain accuracy

Tags: algorithm, combinations

Let's say I have set containing thousands of arrays (let's fix it to 5000 of arrays) of a fixed size (size = 8) with non negative values. And I'm given another array of the same size with non negative values (Input Array). My task is to select some subset of arrays, with the condition that if I sum them together (summation of vectors) I would get the resultant array which is very close to a given Input Array with the desired accuracy (+-m).

For example if the desired result (input array) is (3, 2, 5) and accuracy = 2
Then of course the best set would be the one that would sum up to exactly (3,2,5) but also any solution of the following form would be ok (3 +- m, 2 +- m, 5 +- m).

The question is what could be the right algorithmic approach here? It is similar to multi dimensional sack problem, but there is no cost optimization section in my task.

At least one solution is required which meets the constraints. But several would be better, so that it would be possible to have a choice.

Comment: What about standard brute-force backtracking? If the `input Array and `m` is small enough compare to average values = like in general you usually put 5 arrays as possible solution before you hit boundaries (one of the `input value` bigger or smaller than `m`) then it is countable.

Comment: @libik thats good point if the solution can be found with 5 arrays let's say. but I'm more interested in general case, what if the input array values are big and any 5 arrays from the main set won't be enough?

Comment: its NPC problem (or for multidimensional maybe even np-hard), so in general - you cannot compute best solution in reasonable time. You will need to use some heuristic, what about simulated annealing? https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/021e/fd45493c2899a485a7012eae913075323b55.pdf

Comment: agree, but I'm searching for at least some solution. the link there is the task with two conditions, fill the bag and get maximum of something. where in my case I just need to fill the bag without additional conditions to optimize. let me think if I could remake that algorithm for my case.

Comment: @libik I wonder if I could change all profit to zero and use the standard algorithm (or the one in your link)? so the task would be just to meet the constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of extended knapsack problem. We know that it is NPC task to do which mean = we cannot use bruteforce and try all possibilities. It is just not computable with current computers.

What we can do is use some heuristic. One simple and useful is the `simulated annealing`. The principle is quite simple - at beginning of your algorithm, when the temperature is high - you are not afraid to take even the "at the moment worse solution" (which can actually lead to the best possible solution). So at beginning you take almost anything. Then you start cooling and more cool you are, the more causius you are so you are trying to improve your solution more and more and risk less and less.

The gifs on wiki are actually nice example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing

I have also implemented solution that at the end prints whats the inputArray and what is your solution and the "negative score" (the less the better).

You are not guaranteed to get best/valid solution, but you can basically run this in some while cycle until you find solution good enough or you hit some threshold (like if you do not find good solution after running 100x times, you say "data not valid" or take the best of these "not good" solutions)

```js
class Simulation {
    constructor(size, allArrSize, inputArrayRange, ordinarySize, maxDif, overDifPenalisation) {
        this.size = size;
        this.allArrSize = allArrSize;
        this.inputArrayRange = inputArrayRange;
        this.ordinarySize = ordinarySize;
        this.maxDif = maxDif;
        this.overDifPenalisation = overDifPenalisation;

        this.allArr = [];
        this.solutionMap = new Map();
        for (let i = 0; i < allArrSize; i++) {
            let subarr = [];
            for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                subarr.push(Math.round(Math.random() * ordinarySize));
            }
            this.allArr.push(subarr);
        }

        this.temperature = 100;
        this.inputArray = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            this.inputArray.push(Math.round(Math.random() * inputArrayRange));
        }
    }

    findBest() {
        while (this.temperature > 0) {
            const oldScore = this.countScore(this.solutionMap);
            // console.log(oldScore);
            let newSolution = new Map(this.solutionMap);

            if (this.addNewOrRemove(true)) {
                const newCandidate = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.allArrSize);
                newSolution.set(newCandidate, true);
            } else if (this.addNewOrRemove(false)) {
                const deleteCandidate = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.solutionMap.size);
                Simulation.deleteFromMapByIndex(newSolution, deleteCandidate);
            } else {
                const deleteCandidate = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.solutionMap.size);
                Simulation.deleteFromMapByIndex(newSolution, deleteCandidate);
                const newCandidate = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.allArrSize);
                newSolution.set(newCandidate, true);
            }

            const newScore = this.countScore(newSolution);
            if (newScore < oldScore) {
                this.solutionMap = newSolution;
            } else if ((newScore - oldScore) / newScore < this.temperature / 300) {
                this.solutionMap = newSolution;
            }

            this.temperature -= 0.001;
        }

        console.log(this.countScore(this.solutionMap), 'Negative Score');
        console.log(this.sumTheSolution(this.solutionMap).toString(), 'Solution');
        console.log(this.inputArray.toString(), 'Input array');
        console.log('Solution is built on these inputs:');            
        this.solutionMap.forEach((val, key) => console.log(this.allArr[key].toString()))
    }

    addNewOrRemove(addNew) {
        const sum = this.sumTheSolution(this.solutionMap);

        let dif = 0;
        sum.forEach((val, i) => {
            const curDif = this.inputArray[i] - val;
            if (curDif < -this.maxDif) {
                dif -= 1;
            }
            if (curDif > this.maxDif) {
                dif += 1;
            }
        });

        let chance;
        if (addNew) {
            chance = (dif + this.size - 1) / (this.size * 2);
        } else {
            chance = (-dif + this.size - 1) / (this.size * 2);
        }

        return chance > Math.random();
    }

    countScore(solution) {
        const sum = this.sumTheSolution(solution);

        let dif = 0;
        sum.forEach((val, i) => {
            let curDif = Math.abs(this.inputArray[i] - val);
            if (curDif > this.maxDif) {
                curDif += (curDif - this.maxDif) * this.overDifPenalisation;
            }
            dif += curDif;
        });

        return dif;
    }

    sumTheSolution(solution) {
        const sum = Array(this.size).fill(0);
        solution.forEach((unused, key) => this.allArr[key].forEach((val, i) => sum[i] += val));
        return sum;
    }

    static deleteFromMapByIndex(map, index) {
        let i = 0;
        let toDelete = null;
        map.forEach((val, key) => {
            if (index === i) {
                toDelete = key;
            }
            i++;
        });
        map.delete(toDelete);
    }
}

const simulation = new Simulation(8, 5000, 1000, 100, 40, 100);
simulation.findBest();
```

You can play a bit with numbers to get waht you need (the speed of cooling, how it affects probability, some values in constructor etc.)

Comment: Interesting approach. Though fit high accuracy it would still take lots of time. Is there a chance that some different approach would do that faster? I'm running with 3000 items and want to get something which is in range of +-5. And btw it seems like the delete candidate should be selected from newSolution instead of solutionMap?

Comment: @maximus - you should experiment with it a bit. Maybe running it multiple times with temperature going down faster brings you the answer faster. It depends on data you have, your constrainsts (how much cases you have to compute in a minute, what infrastructure you can use for that) etc.

If you "buy" EC2 machines with 2 cores on AWS for an hour it costs 0.09$, so maybe you can create some scripts and run it there from time to time for a few hours...?

Comment: @maximus - maybe if you put some sample data somewhere, it can be more useful. The `maxDif=5` does not tell much without what is the value of `inputArray` and what are the values of `allArr`

Comment: actually it seems like running multiple times with higher speed could give desired result faster than running once with slower speed and lots of time spent for waiting, amazing!

Comment: @maximus - yea, also maybe for your data, the "high temperature" does not give good results anyway, so you can start with i.e. `temperature=20` or have `this.temperature / 1000` (and going down with temperature with even higher speed)